# Detecting a Collision Between Two Bodies Undergoing Multiple Transformations

Tags: collision-detection, game-physics, physics

I have been searching for an answer to this for a really long time and I have not found any definitive answers as of yet.  What I am trying to do is determine if and when two bodies collided between the times `t0` and `t1`.  Calculating this is much more straight forward if each body is only either translating or rotating (about center or any point), but when adding multiple transformations on top of each other, things become a bit more messy.  I made this animation to illustrate the problem.

[image: Animation]

As you can see, at times `t0` and `t1` there are no collisions, but between there are multiple collisions occurring.

One way I thought of for tackling this problem was to reduce the size of the time intervals.  So, between `t0` and `t1` there would be a total of `n` updates to check for collisions.  This works, but the only way I found that I could guarantee no false negatives, i.e. not finding a collision that happened, was to integrate over extremely small time-steps.  As you can imagine, this is very costly because it resulted in the tens to hundreds of time-steps per body per update cycle.  I am not saying this idea has no merit, but I would need to find a way to calculate the minimum number of time-steps rather than uniformly moving each body forward one unit of distance/rotation until they reach the desired position and orientation.

So, my question is two parts:

1. Is there a better way of determining if and when a collision occurs?
2. If not, is it possible to calculate the minimum number of time-steps?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this problem can be solved in general. If we view time as a third spatial axis, the problem is equivalent to finding any intersection between the bodies traced out by the outline of the two shapes between times *t_1* and *t_2*. The best (most accurate) thing to do is probably to use small time-steps and consider intersections between any two 3d 'slices' spanned between time *t_m* and *t_(m+1)*. But this will not be much better than considering just the 2d-figures..

As for the second part, probably no - but perhaps you can iterate the simulation with a time-step that depends upon the nearest distance between the two figures and the speed with which this distance changes? This will probably improve accuracy and processing speed, but it still does not guarantee finding all intersections.

If you do, I would propose a time-step, *dt*, something like

dt = Min(f * d / Max(-v, v_min), DT), where

DT is the maximum time-step you will allow,

d is the distance between the nearest points in the figures,

v is the speed with which this distance changes (negative, if they approach each other),

v_min is some minimum (positive) speed you consider realistic to model,

f is some factor less than one to minimize the number of false positives produced by sudden 'jumps' in speed between the two objects.

Finally, you can model some circles around the figures' points of rotation and safely move the figures as long as the circles are not intersecting (you only have to translate the circles, since they are invariant under rotation) - then you can use small time-steps for as long as these circles intersect.

I hope some of this helps.